# Pedigree Chart into Spreadsheet from GEDCOM

Tags: gedcom, software-recommendations

I have a spreadsheet, of my own creation, which I call Custom_Lines_Chasing, which, in its essence, is a pedigree chart.

I paste below a screen shot, of a small part, so that you can see its format.

[image: Extract of spreadsheet named Cousin_Lines_Chasing]

I find this to be an invaluable tool to manage my research.

In connection with a publication project, for which I am the lead author, I am, hopefully soon, to be receieving many GEDCOMS regarding extended families who are linked, at at least one point, to the extended family of my paternal grandmother, from each of which I will want to create a similar spreadsheet.

I am wondering whether anyone might be aware of a program that could 'extract', from a GEDCOM, a spreadsheet pedigree chart, which is akin to what I have posted above.

Comment: Welcome to Genealogy & Family History. I've edited your question to remove your name because that really should go in your profile (which you can edit yourself). We don't have a tag for Programming because that's explicitly off-topic here (as per https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I have no experience of this http://www.gedmagic.com/GEDxlate.htm but you may want to try it. If somebody else who is familiar with it wants to construct an answer, I'll delete this comment. Ditto if you would like to self-answer after trying it.

Comment: Dear ColeValleyGirl, thank you for the welcome.  I have found and tried GEDxlate.  While it goes a small way towards my requirement, it really only gets about 20% there, a reverse, so to say, of the classic 80/20 situation.  I am, though, just now, in correspondence, with Rick Seelhoff, who wrote the program 13 years ago, to see if he is interested in enhancing the product.  You removed my name and asked me to edit my profile, instead.  I have gone to the board's home page, but I cannot see how and where to get to my profile, please advise.

Answer (score 1):

I know that you said that you want to use your own spreadsheet for this but have you considered doing it in a different way and using a conventional genealogy programme to do this? For instance Family Historian uses gedcom as its file storage method, it has a query tool built in that could create the type of list that you are wanting. If you definitely want to keep using a spreadsheet then the result of such a query can be exported as a CSV file and that could be input to your spreadsheet. Family Historian is available as a 30 day free trial so it may well be worth doing a test with it. It is available [here](https://www.family-historian.co.uk/downloads)

Comment: Dear Colin.  Thank you for that suggestion.  I already store my tree on both MyHeritage and Ancestry, and their local PC counterparts, FTB and FTM but I will explore Family Historian.  My research is primarily driven through Ancestry.